# Using Meta Viewport Width Causes Overflowing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow, viewport

I have a requirement for my Webflow website to load entirely zoomed out on all devices, so I've added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1600"/>` to the head of my project in an attempt to solve this. The problem is that I'm still seeing what looks like roughly 150-200px of overflow on an iPhone 6 in portrait mode (375px width). iPhone 6 landscape and iPad all work great...

The strange part is that this fits perfectly if I set the viewport width to 1400, so why does 1600+ make a difference? Surely it should just show the content at the width that I specify. Also, you'd think that if one of 1400 and 1600 were to overflow, it would be the lower width that would have the issue

I thought this was perhaps due to the elements, but I set-up a new page which only had a body element and it was still overflowing by roughly the same amount.

Here's an image of how the page loads:

[image]

Here's how it looks if I set the viewport width to 1400 rather than 1600.

[image]

Thank you to anybody who can help me here

Comment: but giving explicit values will not lead to a responsive design.

Comment: That's no problem, I require for this website to specifically not be at all responsive. I wish for it to load on any device fully zoomed out at 1600px (or any viewport width I set).

Comment: add initial-scale=1.0 or a value that good for your needs.

Comment: Sorry I've already tried this, in fact i've tried almost every setting I could find.